# Extracting value nodes from XML C string representation

Tags: c, string

I have a string representation of an xml line. What is the best method to retrieve the inside node values as strings?

```
char *str = "<heading>Reminder</heading><body>Don't forget me this weekend!</body>"
```

Comment: well, unless things are really strict and a regexp work, I think you are better off learning to use a real XML parser.  Something like parsifal (small, mostly self-contained) http://www.saunalahti.fi/~samiuus/toni/xmlproc/ or libxml2 http://xmlsoft.org/ if you don't mind the dependencies.  XML is a complex beast, so doing your own parser via regexp etc usually comes back to haunt you unless your cases are really "static".

Comment: What are you trying to do? can you explain what is your goal?

Answer (score 0):

The best method depends on complexity of the XML stream you expect. It the string is really that easy as in your example, I would code it manually, with functions like strtok_r or scanf.
If you think, that the data structure may become more complex and the nesting will increase, I would use a dedicated library, as proposed before.
Further: How much error treatment do you need?